# Ubuntu server in VirtualBox: no connection to host

Tags: server, ssh

For an assignment I need to host 2 websites using nginx. The default page worked yesterday, now it doesn't (I haven't changed anything significant though) and I also can't open an SSH connection anymore (which also used to work yesterday)
Also, I can't ping to or from the server.

I have configured 1 bridged network interface, and 2 host-only interfaces.
ifconfig looks like this (Sorry for the bad indentation, here's a screenshot too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYnwA.png)

```
enp0s3 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:27:92:36
 inet addr:192.168.0.100 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: 2a02:1812:d1c:1700:a00:27ff:fe27:9236/64 
  Scope:Globa inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe27:9236/64 
  Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:69110 (69.1 NB) TX bytes:2200 (2.2 NB) 
enp0s8 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:82:2a:43
 inet addr:192.168.0.101 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe82:2a43/64 
  Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:63669 (63.6 NB) TX bytes:648 (648.0 B) 
enp0s9 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:bd:75:43
 inet addr:192.168.0.102 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:febd:7543/64 
  Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX b tes:70850 (70.8 NB) TX b tes:648 (648.0 B)
```

Thanks in advance, if anything is unclear, please ask !